# Powershell C# Cmdlet Set InformationAction

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am creating the PowerShell cmdlet in C#. To enable support for pipeline I have used `WriteObject` to expose the output to the next cmdlet in the pipeline.

However, now I want to display basic status information about the cmdlet result like "Task Completed". To display this information, I am using `WriteInformation` method.
However, the message is not displayed if the `InformationAction` is not set.

Can we set the `InformationAction` in the code so that by default it is always set to `Continue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it by:

> $InformationPreference="Continue"

Comment: I want to achieve this in C# cmdlet. Can we access this variable in the Cmdlet code(C#)?

Comment: @Scorp Try: this.SessionState.PSVariable.Set

Comment: Yes , this worked. Thanks. Just curious if we can set this once for all the cmdlets exposed from my module.